# How can messages be retained in a Flask website?

Tags: variables, flask, global

I'm new to Flask and trying to understand how to retain variable values. To do this, I'm trying to write a small application that can accept message inputs, add them to a list and then print out that list. My code isn't working and I'm not sure why. I would appreciate guidance on this problem (and on any other obvious problems).

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask import redirect

class Server(Flask):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Server, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.messages = []

server = Server(__name__)

@server.route('/')
def form():
    return "messages: " + server.messages

@server.route("/input_message")
def input_message():
    return '<form action="/store_message" method="GET"><input name="input1"><input type="submit" value="enter message"></form>'

@server.route("/store_message")
def store_message(): 
    server.messages.append(request.args.get('input1', ''))
    return redirect("http://127.0.0.1:5000", code = 302)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    server.run(
        host = "127.0.0.1",
        port = "5000"
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example `server.messages` is a list, but you're treating it like a string so `"messages:" + server.messages` is going to lead to an error.  You want something like `"messages: " + ",".join(server.messages)`